# Ошибка розметки PHP файлов в PHPStorm (No data sources are configured to run this SQL ...)

Tags: php, phpstorm

Ошибка розметки PHP файлов в PHPStorm.
Не понимаю в чем проблема как мне это исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
    <li><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
    <li><?=Lang::translation('faq_main_title',false)?></li>
</ul>
<div class="content-header">
    <h1 class="content-title"><?=Lang::translation('faq_main_title',false)?></h1>
</div>
<div class="faq-page">




    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    <?php foreach($faq as $item): ?>
        <?php if(Lang::getLang() == 1): ?>
    <div class="faq-item">
        <a href="#" class="faq-title active"><?=$i?>. <?=$item->title_ukr?></a>
        <div class="faq-answer">
            <p><?=$item->text_ukr?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <div class="faq-item">
                <a href="#" class="faq-title active"><?=$i?>. <?=$item->title_rus?></a>
                <div class="faq-answer">
                    <p><?=$item->text_rus?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
```

Ошибка:
       No data sources are configured to run this SQL and provide advanced code assistance. Disable this inspection via problem menu (⌥⏎). less... (⌘F1) 
Prompts one to create a data source if there is none.

Comment: File-> Invalidate Caches/Restart

Comment: @rjhdby  Не помогло